# How do I restore the session ID for Express Session Authentication in a NativeScript app?

Tags: cookies, nativescript

Buckle up, this one's a little bit complicated. I know that Express sends the browser a `connect.sid` cookie... and Passport uses this to deserialize the User on web requests. Not only that, but when I log in to my application from my NativeScript app (I'm running on a Pixel 2 emulator on a Windows PC, but I know it also works on iOS), the cookie seems to be correctly set and sent along with future web requests. I also understand how the `application-settings` API works, and that you can use this to store a user-identifying token for future boots of the application (so that I don't have to log in every time).

So here's where the disconnect occurs. Conceivably I can override the cookie in the request header if I have it stored, but nowhere can I find documentation on how to retrieve a cookie from the successful login request in nativescript.

Here's the code:

**TokenSvc**

```
import { Injectable }     from "@angular/core";
import { getString, setString } from "application-settings";

export class TokenSvc {
   static isLoggedIn(): boolean {
      return !!getString("token");
   }

   static get token(): string {
      return getString("token");
   }

   static set token(token: string) {
      setString("token", token);
   }
}
```

**Login Component**

(Note I am making an embarrassing attempt at getting the cookies from a new HttpHeaders instance... not sure why I thought that would work.)

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"]
})
export class LoginComponent {
    credentials: ILoginCredentials;
    @ViewChild("password") password: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("handle") handle: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("confirmPassword") confirmPassword: ElementRef;

    constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router, private AuthSvc: AuthSvc, private _store: Store<AppStore>) {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.credentials = {
           email: "",
           password: "",
           cPassword: "",
           handle: "",
           publicName: ""
        };
    }


    login() {
        const loginCredentials: ICredentials = {
            username: this.credentials.email,
            password: this.credentials.password,
            rememberMe: false
        };
        this.AuthSvc.login(loginCredentials).subscribe(
            (payload) => {
                console.log(payload);
                if (payload.failure) {
                    alert(payload.failure);
                } else {
                    // user!
                    let cookies = new HttpHeaders().get("Cookie");
                    console.log(cookies);
                    TokenSvc.token = cookies;
                    this._store.dispatch({ type: "SET_USER", payload: payload });
                    this.router.navigate(["/tabs"]);
                }
            }, () => alert("Unfortunately we were unable to create your account.")
      );
   }

}
```

The essential question here is... how do I persist a cookie-based session in NativeScript application-settings with a Node/Express back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential answer is: you don't.

Prefer JWT, OAuth2 or any other token-based authentication method when it comes to mobile development. You can use the same authentication method for web too.

Store the user token using [the secure storage](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-secure-storage) and send the token along with any request made by the user.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. That's what the consensus on the internet seems to be.